# Excel Like AVERAGE FUNCTION in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: sql, average, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find equivalent of the AVERAGE() excel function in Snowflake, but I can't seem find it.

I want to do the following in Snowflake, where AVG_CustomFunc is a custom function and the parameter list can grow upto 100 arguments(255 in excel):

```
SELECT AVG_CustomFunc(tab.col1, tab.col2, tab.col3)
from tab
```

or

```
SELECT AVG_CustomFunc(tab.col1, tab.col2)
from tab
```

IF tab has 3 column where col1 => 1, col2 => 2 & col3 => 3, I am expecting result as 2.0 for first query and 1.5 for second query

Initially though of creating single function with default values however Snowflake currently doesn't allow default values in function parameter

is there any other solution or suggestions to this

Comment: Well, there is [documentation for it](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/avg.html). Are you getting your syntax right?

Comment: I am aware of AVG function in Snowflake, I want to create a custom function which will do a average on columns rather on rows

Comment: Have you thought about pivoting the data first, in that case, then averaging?

Comment: Are `NULL` values an issue?

Comment: I need to ignore {NULL} values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using Javascript functions

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AVGF (STR VARCHAR)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS $$
    var str_array = String(STR).split(",");
    var total = 0.0
    for (i = 0; i < str_array.length; i += 1) {
        total += parseFloat(str_array[i]);
    }
    return total/str_array.length;
  $$
  ;
```

Now I can do

```
SELECT AVGF(tab.col1, tab.col2)
from tab
```

and

```
SELECT AVGF(tab.col1, tab.col2, tab.col3)
from tab
```

Answer (score 0):

`AVG()` is an aggregate function, that operates on groups of rows.

You want the computation on a single line, so just use arithmetics. If none of the values is `null`:

```
(col1 + col2 + col3) / 3 as myavg
```

If we want to handle nulls as `AVG()` does:

```
(coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2, 0) + coalesce(col3, 0))
    / nullif(
        case when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end
            + case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end
            + case when col3 is null then 0 else 1 end,
        0) as myavg
```

Comment: what if the number of columns is known only at runtime?

Comment: @AnupThomas: I woulud say that if you have an undefined number of columns at run time, then you might have a bigger problem that what you explain here. Basically this means you need dynamic SQL, which seems beyond the scope of your original question

Comment: You are right! May be I should edit my question .. will do .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`LATERAL` and `AVG` aggregate function should suffice:

```
SELECT tab.*, s.calc_average
FROM tab,
LATERAL (SELECT AVG(sub.col) AS calc_average
        FROM(SELECT tab.col1 UNION ALL SELECT tab.col2 UNION ALL SELECT tab.col3) sub(col)
        ) s;
```

It will behave like standard `AVG` no need to add additional NULL handling, and could be easily expanded to incorporate more columns.

Comment: I still cannot create function as it throws unsupported subquery error

Answer (score 0):

Does this formulation work with arrays?

```
select t.*,
       (select avg(value)
        from flatten(input => t.ar)
       )
from (select t.*, array_construct_compact(col1, col2, . . . ) as ar
      from t
     ) t ;
```

Comment: I cannot create function as it throws unsupported subquery error

Comment: @AnupThomas . . . Thank you for checking.  The Snowflake `flatten()` is much less versatile than `unnest()` in other databases.  That's a shame, I hope they get around to fixing that.  This type of construct has some significant performance advantages on parallel databases.